# Limit phpMyAdmin installed by apt to one Apache Virtual host

Tags: apache2, mysql, phpmyadmin

I've got several Virtual host setup on my web server and I only want one of them to be able to access the phpMyAdmin install?

Ubuntu version 16.04

I got on my server setup with 3 vhost that are:
example1.domain.local
example2.domain.local
example3.domain.local

Now if I enter in my web browser any of those with /phpmyadmin I get the phpmyadmin login but I only what to be able to access it from example3.domain.local/phpmyadmin

Fix by removing phpmyadmin.conf using a2disconf.  Then edited etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example3.conf

```
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
Options FollowSymLinks
DirectoryIndex index.php
</Directory>
```

Comment: Could you clarify more? Typically when phpmyadmin is installed, it will default itself to localhost/phpmyadmin.

Comment: You have several _virtual hosts_ set up for _phpmyadmin_, is that what you mean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable phpmyadmin in apache2.conf.
Enable in virtual host for you choice.

## phpMyAdmin /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/yourvirtualhost.conf

```
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
Options FollowSymLinks
DirectoryIndex index.php
</Directory>
```

Comment: in my version of ubunts the phpmyadmin is not in the apache2.conf it is its own configuration file that you have to remove with a2disconf